# 'Domain Users' Security Group has Admin Rights

Tags: active-directory, microsoft

I took over for a previous network admin. He had all 'Domain Users' have admin rights for some reason..
How do I see what makes 'Domain Users' security group have admin rights?
It is not added into 'Domain Admins' or 'Administrators' security group.
I ran gpresult /v on a domain user and it says its part of the 'built in administrators' group.
domain controller: Windows Server 2008

Comment: If `BUILTIN\Administrators` is showing up when you run `gpresult /v`, that means the logged on user is part of that group. What makes you believe that Domain Users has admin rights?